# Подменить файл в input file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Алгоритм программы такова:

1. Выбираем файл или несколько файлов (`input file`);
2. Заменяем файл с другим вариантом (в `input file`);
3. Отправляем в сервер php замененный вариант, с помощью `input submit`.

Как подменить файл в `input file`?

Answer (score 0):

Никак. Этот инпут только для того и придумали, чтобы из соображений безопасности возможно было в браузере обрабатывать только тот файл(-ы), который был на компьютере выбран пользователем. Если бы можно было подменять, то можно было бы выбирать с компа файлы в фоновом режиме без input file.